# Getting a blank page after after deploying reactjs app to github pages

Tags: reactjs, github

Hi I'm trying to deploy my reactjs app to GitHub pages but I keep getting a blank page
here are the steps I followed

1. Pushing project to empty repo: https://github.com/DroidBarber/dolla
2. installing gh-pages: `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`
3. modifying package.json :

```
{
"homepage": "https://DroidBarber.github.io/dolla/",
},
scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
},
```

4. deploying `npm run deploy`

but I'm getting a blank page app runs fine in local host...

Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deploying your application to an additional path: /dolla/.
So when your deployed react application run on: https://DroidBarber.github.io/dolla/ it tries to get resources from /dolla/ which is not defined in your routing.
[image: See pathName]

It will be similar when you run on your local at http://localhost:3000/dolla

Try to change your homepage in webpack to: "homepage": "https://DroidBarber.github.io/".

Comment: Yes, you're actually correct, i noticed that too, thanks a lot

Comment: Np mate. I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages doesn't support the `pushState` history API (which react-router-dom's `BrowserRouter` uses under the hood). You'll need to switch to `HashRouter` instead. You can read more about it [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing)