# React app showing blank page after deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, react-router-dom, github-pages

I've previously created and deployed single-page react apps on GitHub and netlify and they all worked fine. the problem is with multi-page apps using react-router. to test this I tried several times with different apps and as soon as I implement react-router and link to different pages, they become blank after deployment. here's a test app:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
 root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
     <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Index from "./pages/Index";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Products from "./pages/Products";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

const App = () => {
return (
<>
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Index />} />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
  </Routes>
</>
 );
}; 

export default App;
```

Navbar.js component

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
 return (
   <>
   <nav className="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">about</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/products">products</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</>
);
};

export default Navbar;
```

Package.json

```
{
 "name": "test-app",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "homepage": "https://EricSsSnake/github.io/test-app",
 "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
 },
  "scripts": {
   "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
  "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": [
   "react-app",
   "react-app/jest"
    ]
   },
  "browserslist": {
   "production": [
   ">0.2%",
   "not dead",
   "not op_mini all"
   ],
  "development": [
   "last 1 chrome version",
   "last 1 firefox version",
   "last 1 safari version"
   ] 
  },
 "devDependencies": {
  "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
 }
}
```

plus 3 pages to navigate to.

When I deploy this on GitHub all I get is a blank page with these errors. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZTzq.png)

for deployment, I follow this tutorial:
[react-gh-pages](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages)

I'd really appreciate your help guys. this issue has stopped me from making any progress. I spent 3 weeks making my portfolio and now it's just sitting there.

**update**:
replacing BrowserRouter with HashRouter fixed the initial problem and there are no longer any errors in the console. however, what I'm getting now is a blank page, as if the route that the index page is set to doesn't exist.
I think the problem I have now is similar to this thread:
[Getting a blank page after deploying reactjs app to github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701401/getting-a-blank-page-after-after-deploying-reactjs-app-to-github-pages)

Comment: Try using `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`. I know it won't fix it but then we can rule out the possibility of JS not being able to handle routes other than root. Or similar issues.

Comment: Commenting because im not sure if this works! but try adding a basename. `<BrowserRouter basename="/test-app">`. if applying this fixed your problem, you need to revise your server configurations.

Answer (score 3):

**change  :**

```
"homepage": "https://EricSsSnake/github.io/test-app",
```

**to :**

```
"homepage": "https://EricSsSnake.github.io/test-app",
```

and use **HashRouter** instead of **BrowserRouter** .
in your case change  your **index.js** like this :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
 root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
     <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

**Note :**  githup pages do not support React Router with `browserHistory` because it's using **HTML5 history API**  that's why you can switch to to routing with hashes ( `HashRouter` in react router) check in the official doc of [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)

Comment: let me know if it didn't work

Comment: Thanks your solution solved the problem but another one arose :( There are no longer any errors in the console but now what I get is a blank page. my navbar is rendered but when I click on any link it shows a 404 message. so it doesn't fully render the index page and cannot find any of the other pages.

Comment: I updated the question and explained the new problem at the end. would you kindly take a look

Comment: In the **navbar** component change `a` tag to `Link` like this `<Link to="/">home</Link>`  and `<Link to="/about">about</Link>` and `<Link to="/products">products</Link>`  don't forget to `import Link from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: I'll update my answer if it worked

Comment: please update the navbar in your question to check if everything is okey ! and just get rid of **StrictMode** in your index.js

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error in the console?

If not, try using `<Link />` component imported from 'react-router-dom' or 'react-router' instead of '' provided by html, because `<a>` will trigger a page refresh and `<Link />` won't.

hope this answer help you