# Deployed React app on GitHub Pages showing a blank page

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

When I open the page is just blank (it shows absolutely nothing). I run it locally and it works perfectly.

I followed step by step the GitHub instructions.

- Repository: https://github.com/Francis-MD/TEST
- Web deployment: https://francis-md.github.io/TEST/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your App.tsx contains "BrowserRouter".
Github pages can't read it.
Try changing it to "HashRouter".
I had a similar issue with my project and this strategy worked for me.
You can see more details and also alternative strategies in this Stack Overflow post -> [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73888210/react-js-project-on-github-pages-not-showing)
Good luck!

Comment: I have tried, but also does not work.  I went a bit deeper implementing other suggestions I saw in other posts here, but still not working :/